# MongoDB Java Driver 3.x authenticate after connecting

Tags: java, mongodb

We are using a „Database per tenant“ strategy to, means every customer has its own MongoDB database (not MongoDB instance).  Every database has its own user.
https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/securing-mongodb-to-serve-an-aws-based-multi-tenant-security-fanatic-saas-application

To be able to use connection pooling I need to connect to the Mongo instance (or replica set) without a user or a common user and change the connection and authenticate once needed.

The documentation of the shell describes how to do that:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

- connect
- use admin
- db.auth (user, admin)

But this functionality is not available in the Java Driver.
I know that I can pass the credentials during the initialization of the MongoClient but I keep the MongoClient as a Singleton (as recommended). Adding a new tenant would mean reinitialize the MongoClient.

Maybe the runCommand could do the trick but I don’t know the BSON of the authenticate command

Regards,
Thomas